# Angular lazy load a service

Tags: angular

What is the recommended approach to lazy loading a service class. Here is what I have in mind:

Create a feature module `foo`, which contains foo.component.ts, where the foo.module provides the service and the service is injected into foo.component. As a result the service will only be loaded if you navigate to the foo.component and the route is defined as follows:

app.-routing.module.ts:

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'foo',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./foo/foo.module').then((m) => m.FooModule),
  },
];
...
```

Is there also another way to lazy load a service, because it's not necessary to navigate to another component? It would be enough if I can call the service when button is clicked inside the app.component. But the **requirement** is, that the **service is only injected/loaded after the button was clicked.**

app.component.ts:

```
import { BarService } from './foo/bar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <button (click)="runService()">Run Service</button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private barService: BarService) {}

  runService() {
    this.barService.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [wrote about this](https://riegler.fr/blog/2023-09-30-lazy-loading-mockable) recently.

If you want to lazy-load a service programmatically, you will need to use a dynamic import : `const myService = import('./myService.ts')`

But by doing this you will be limited in your tests, you would be able to mock that service. This is why I wrote that function :

```
export async function injectAsync<T>(
  injector: Injector,
  providerLoader: () => Promise<ProviderToken<T>>,
): Promise<T> {
  const injectImpl = injector.get(InjectAsyncImpl);
  return injectImpl.get(injector, providerLoader);
}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
class InjectAsyncImpl<T> {
  private overrides = new WeakMap(); // no need to cleanup
  override<T>(type: Type<T>, mock: Type<unknown>) {
    this.overrides.set(type, mock);
  }

  async get(injector: Injector, providerLoader: () => Promise<ProviderToken<T>>): Promise<T> {
    const type = await providerLoader();

    // Check if we have overrides, O(1), low overhead
    if (this.overrides.has(type)) {
      const module = this.overrides.get(type);
      return new module();
    }

    if (!(injector instanceof EnvironmentInjector)) {
      // We're passing a node injector to the function

      // This is the DestroyRef of the component
      const destroyRef = injector.get(DestroyRef);

      // This is the parent injector of the environmentInjector we're creating
      const environmentInjector = injector.get(EnvironmentInjector);

      // Creating an environment injector to destroy it afterwards
      const newInjector = createEnvironmentInjector([type as Provider], environmentInjector);

      // Destroy the injector to trigger DestroyRef.onDestroy on our service
      destroyRef.onDestroy(() => {
        newInjector.destroy();
      });

      // We want to create the new instance of our service with our new injector 
      injector = newInjector;
    }

    return injector.get(module)!;
  }
}

/**
 * Helper function to mock the lazy-loaded module in `injectAsync`
 *
 * @usage
 * TestBed.configureTestingModule({
 *     providers: [
 *     mockAsyncProvider(SandboxService, fakeSandboxService)
 *   ]
 * });
 */
export function mockAsyncProvider<T>(type: Type<T>, mock: Type<unknown>) {
  return [
    {
      provide: ENVIRONMENT_INITIALIZER,
      multi: true,
      useValue: () => {
        inject(InjectAsyncImpl).override(type, mock);
      },
    },
  ];
}
```

Also this function handles the usage of `DestroyRef` used by `takeUntilDestroyed`.